# horizontal ggplot2::geom_violin without coord_flip

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw horizontal violin plots (because my labels are long).  My design constraints are:

- multiple facets (`f1`), multiple categories per facet (`f2`) (so I want to use `aes(x=f2)` and `facet_wrap(~f1)`
- different scales per facet (so I want `scales="free"`)
- 4 different facets which I want to arrange via `facet_wrap()` (ruling out some faceting tricks)

Unfortunately `scales="free"` and `coord_flip()` are currently (and for the foreseeable future) incompatible.

The answers to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560858/using-coord-flip-with-facet-wrapscales-free-y-in-ggplot2-seems-to-give-u) suggest (1) hacking a new horizontal geom; (2) exchanging `x` and `y` (which as pointed out there works only with symmetric geoms like scatterplots); (3) giving up and going with the conventional layout.

Ideas?

```
set.seed(101)
library("plyr")
dd <- expand.grid(f1=factor(1:2),
     f2=paste("inconveniently long label",1:2))
dd2 <- ddply(dd,c("f1","f2"),
             function(x)
                 data.frame(y=rnorm(100,
                         mean=10*(as.numeric(x$f2)), 
                         sd=10^(as.numeric(x$f1)))))
library("ggplot2")
```

My choices seem to be (1) with `scale="free"`, inconvenient (horizontal) labels:

```
ggplot(dd2,aes(x=f2,y=y))+facet_wrap(~f1,scale="free")+geom_violin()
```

[image]

(2) with `coord_flip()`, inconvenient scales

```
ggplot(dd2,aes(x=f2,y=y))+facet_wrap(~f1)+geom_violin()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

Trying both (`ggplot(dd2,aes(x=f2,y=y))+facet_wrap(~f1,scale="free")+geom_violin()+coord_flip()`) gives

> ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip.

Other ideas:

- There are explicitly horizontal versions of some geoms (`geom_errorbarh`); I could hack my own `geom_violinh` ...
- There is some discussion of horizontal geoms in a [pull request on ggplot2](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1265)
- [This (rather old) example](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-3/) uses facets + `geom_ribbon()` to hack a violin plot, but it uses up faceting, making it incompatible with `facet_wrap()`

For what it's worth, this is what my real plot looks like (at the moment):

[image]

Comment: The question of flipping these still stands but would rotating the x axis labels or breaking them on spaces (i.e., `gsub("\\s+", "\n", "inconveniently long label")`) suit your intended goal?

Comment: I don't like rotating them but I might be willing to break or abbreviate them ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but it's an adaptation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261038/ggplot2-violin-plot-fill-central-95-only/34264845#34264845) answer where we 'hacked' the vertical violin.

```
dd2_violin <- ddply(dd2,.(f1,f2),function(chunk){
  d_y <- density(chunk$y)
  top_part <- data.frame(x=d_y$x, y=d_y$y)
  bottom_part <- top_part[nrow(top_part):1,]
  bottom_part$y <- 0 - bottom_part$y
  return(rbind(top_part,bottom_part))
})
#weird trick to get spacing right
dd2_violin$y2 <- as.numeric(dd2_violin$f2)*(2*max(dd2_violin$y))+dd2_violin$y

p1 <- ggplot(dd2_violin, aes(x=x,y=y2,group=interaction(f1,f2))) + geom_path()
#apply same weird trick to get labels

p1 + facet_grid(~f1,scales="free")+labs(x="y")+
scale_y_continuous(breaks=unique(as.numeric(dd2_violin$f2)*(2*max(dd2_violin$y))),labels=unique(dd2_violin$f2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This can now be done with the new (Jan 2016) [ggstance package](https://github.com/lionel-/ggstance), which provides horizontal versions of a variety of geoms.

```
## if necessary
devtools::install_github("lionel-/ggstance")
## ... data generation stuff from above
require("ggplot2")
require("ggstance")
ggplot(dd2,aes(y=f2,x=y))+facet_wrap(~f1,scale="free")+
    geom_violinh()
```